# HTML/JS: open other website without associated coockies

Tags: javascript, html, http, cookies

I have a web shop which sends my customers to a pretty popular website to redeem their just purchased product (at my site). However, I keep getting complaints that the product has been redeemed at the wrong account. Because the other website is that popular, it often appears that when the customers computer is shared by others the wrong account was logged in (automatically by a coockie).

Now I'm wondering which steps I can take to prevent this from happening, since I don't have control over the other website (which does not make clear enough who's logged in).

Is there some way to open another website without its coockies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can't get involved in the cookies related to the other site. You'll need to address this by trying to educate your users (and perhaps by contacting the other site about being clear about what user is logged in and such).